# Can GoogleApiClient be used in a Fragment or must it be always used in a Activity?

Tags: android

Can GoogleApiClient be used in a Fragment or must it be always used in a Activity

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 10):

`GoogleApiClient` can work in `Activity`, `Fragment` or `Service`. It needs a `Context` and you can get it by `getApplicationContext()` , `getActivity()` etc. Your `Fragment/Activity` has to implement these two interfaces:

```
implements
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener
```

then you will find these methods:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) { 

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

You have to connect this API client using this `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` and disconnect via `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect()`

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) is the documentation about Accessing Google APIs. [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/02/new-client-api-model-in-google-play.html) is the description. And [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33419346/3073945) has my Demo working code.

Comment: When used in a fragment, `getActivity()` will not work until Callbacks are  implemented by the activity holding the fragment. Rather, `fragment_name.this` or `this` would be the right way to get the context in a fragment and fragment has to implement the callbacks

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can use it within a Fragment. You just have to provide a Context to the builder (which you can use `getActivity()` for) and let the Fragment implement the required interfaces.

```
new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
...
```