# Android localizate device only on GPS

Tags: java, android, google-maps, localization, geolocation

I want to localizate device when i disable GPS. I want also locatizate device while using network or WiFi. Any solutions?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Manifest

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

Gradle

And below is my Activity class on HASTEBIN so you can edit it. I doesn't paste here because code is too big.

[HASTEBIN paste](https://hastebin.com/sojaxexifu.java)

Comment: You are already using Play Services Fused Location. Have you tried adding `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` ? More info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42361598/295004

Comment: I read that FINE_LOCATION have network support

Comment: I added COARSE_LOCATION and still localizate only on GPS

Comment: Please edit you question to include device model and describe how you are doing your testing.